# how to indicate Infinity as sentinel card in mergeSort?

Tags: c, math, merge

I am reading introduction to algorithms,there is a term "sentinel card" that use  ∞ as the sentinel value at P31. I know it means array at the end (and for strings, can use a NULL pointer indicate at the end of strings).   But I don't know how to exactly implement in c programming.

Assume that a int array int A[6] have some random value that must include  -2147483648(INT_MIN), 0 and 2147483647(INT_MAX).

INT_MIN and INT_MAX at /usr/include/limits.h on Linux platform.

For example:

```
int A[6] = {100,0,-2147483648, -100, 2147483646 ,2147483647};
```

so how to indicate ∞ as the sentinel value in c programming at following pseudocode(line 8 and 9)?

```
MERGE (A ,p ,q, r)
 1    n1 = q - p + 1
 2    n2 = r - q
 3    let L[1..n1 + 1] and R[1..n2 + 1] be new arrays
 4    for i = 1 to n1
 5        L[i] = A[p + i - 1]
 6    for j = 1 to n2
 7        R[j] = A[q + j]
 8    L[n1 + 1] =  ∞
 9    R[n2 + 1] =  ∞
10    i = 1
11    j = 1
12    for k = p to r
13        if L[i] <= R[j]
14            A[k] = L[i]
15            i = i + 1
16        else A[k] = R[j]
17            j = j + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One answer would be that ∞ is a number which is larger than your arrays Max by 1 and -∞ is a number that is smaller than your arrays min by 1.And you can make a check each time before calling `MERGE` for what those values are

Comment: if array have a value that is the biggest int value(INT_MAX),so what is number which is larger than your arrays Max by 1